How to fix errors with apt command
I've recently had some errors whilst using the apt command. I was trying to install pi-apps on my system and received some errors about Ubuntu not being able to find packages at ports.ubuntu.com. I recently removed some repositories from my system, but both of these were from ppa.launchpad.com so I don't see why this would affect any of this.
I used the command wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash to install pi-apps and recieved the errors in the image below.
I am using a Raspberry PI running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (I don't know if this will make a difference, but Ubuntu Pro is enabled).


Somehow you are pointing to i386 binaries, even though the script you mentioned should have set it up for arm64 or armhf, depending on which type of Raspberry Pi you are using. This is a bit of a guess, but you can take a look at the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ or the file /etc/apt/sources.list to see what is pointing to the wrong repository and change it as appropriate. If you aren't sure then please post the contents of the file.
